# How to use rpy2 (V3.4.5) with R's tidyr nest()?

Tags: python, r, tidyr, nest, rpy2

My attempt to use `rpy2` in a Jupyter (iPython) notebook fails at the point where I wish to use `tidyr::nest()` to make a dataframe that has some elements which are a series. (This cannot be avoided, it is necessary for the next step of the analysis.)

After trying many things (including advice from [the package home](https://rpy2.github.io/doc/latest/html/introduction.html) I've managed to get most of the way to the end, failing to understand `rpy2` with `tidyr::nest` at the last step. (Some of the following example may be superfluous.)

How can I fix this?

% Import packages

```
from rpy2 import robjects
from rpy2.robjects import Formula, Environment
from rpy2.robjects.vectors import IntVector, FloatVector
from rpy2.robjects.lib import grid
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr, data
from rpy2.rinterface_lib.embedded import RRuntimeError
import warnings

base = importr('base')
datasets = importr('datasets')

from functools import partial

import rpy2.robjects.lib.tidyr as tidyr
from collections import OrderedDict
from rpy2.robjects.vectors import (StrVector,
                                   IntVector)

from rpy2.robjects.lib.tidyr import DataFrame
from rpy2.robjects import rl
 
tidyr = importr('tidyr')
dplyr = importr('dplyr')
```

% Obtain the R dataset "iris"
iris = data(datasets).fetch('iris')['iris']

% Use only two columns necessary for the "tidyr::nest" trial
dataf = (
DataFrame(iris)
.select(base.c(1,5))
)

print(dataf.head())

% Failure occurs below

irisNested = tidyr.nest(dataf, data=rl('Sepal.Length'))

EDIT: This isn't a question anymore, as it turns out my original effort was correct. A fragment of another attempt to solve the problem caused it to fail. However, I asked the question as I didn't find the various sources of help available provided a clear way to address my issue, I felt I made a lucky educated guess.

```
import rpy2.robjects as ro
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
pandas2ri.activate()
```

Removing this solves the problem.

Comment: How does it fail? I can run the example end to end on Jupyter without any error.

Comment: @lgautier I have added the Jupyter output to the end of the question.

Comment: @lgautier you were right, the code does work. The problem was that, before the supplied code, I had a fragment of a past attempt in the notebook which caused the error:
import rpy2.robjects as ro
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
pandas2ri.activate()
I will edit the question accordingly.